# Sitecore Install Assistant failing with CX509PrivateKey Access Denied Error

Tags: sitecore-install-assistant

During the installation of Sitecore 9.3 on a dev workstation, the following error occurs:

> [ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate
>   ------------------] Could not find Cert: DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert in Cert:\LocalMachine\Root CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Access
>   is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

[image]

Sitecore Install Assistant is running as an administrator, passes all pre-req checks and so on.

I usually have no issues creating certificates, trusting them etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you confirm that with your user you have full administrator rights? I faced a different error because of the use was in the administrator group but was not administrator.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat I think that is the problem. I'm an administrator but not the administrator

Answer (score 1):

Please validate you have access rights to create the certificate in `Microsoft Management Console [MMC].`

Seems like access issue while `SIA` trying to create/install the `self signing certificate` for your new Sitecore Website.

Comment: Thank you. I can create self signed certs through IIS management console, in the cert manager MMC I can import certs, request certs.

Answer (score 1):

The user must have administrative privileges to save security files on the machine.  If the user does not have write file permissions, the machine will not be able to generate the private key.

To resolve the error, log in to the machine using a login with administrative rights and try installing it again.

Comment: Thank you. My login is a local administrator, but that right is not sufficient I believe. I need to understand the exact permission needed. I can generate self signed certificates in IIS manager no problems.

I cannot login to the machine as the Administrator account. I work in a large corporate environment and that is not a viable option. I may be able to request the specific permission, even that is going to be difficult. I have verified that SIA is running as elevated.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment, you need to have a privileged to save security files on the machine.

Comment: I'm not sure what save security files is? 
Anyway, I was able to get past that issue when running SIF. I see the certificates in the trusted root. Some odd difference in privileges when running an elevated SIF powershell console vs running from an elevated SIA window. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the comment in the answer so that it can help other people. From the error, it is clear the problem is related to permission as showing `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Now it's a dev workstation where the administrator adds the new user in the `administrator group` which is equivalent to the `administrator` but not the `administrator`. I had a similar issue in where I was installing the Sitecore 9.3 but since I was not a proper admin so from the prerequisites web deploy not installed because of permission.
You need to reach to the your system admin to give proper permission to your account and you will able to install the Sitecore 9.3.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was a permissions issue. Thank you, however, I will need to be more specific than that. I will need to determine exactly what permission is needed. Most large corporate IT departments are not going to just give an entire department of developers broad rights. 

Honestly, we are finding SIA is a bit too fragile. We'll wait for it to evolve over a few more releases. We'll stick to using SIF directly, that gives us more control. The permission issue will remain of course, but we can work around it more easily using SIF directly.

Comment: Just try the PowerShell command `New-SelfSignedCertificate` which also creates a new certificate in the LocalMachine hive. If you can get that to work, likely the SIA will work as well - the permissions needed for the above command are likely much better documented than the APIs used by SIA.

Comment: @RichardHauer - Thanks, yeah SIF has worked. We'll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and this issue was because of full administrator access on the machine - where installation is going on.
Hope you have resolved this issue already.

I am here sharing a solution for this that instead of the SIA way If you will try to setup instance without using SIA. It will work.

Basically with Sitecore setup with PowerShell installation, able to fetch certificate.