# Cannot export non-exportable private key when Installing Sitecore 10

Tags: installation

I am trying to install `Sitecore 10` but getting the below error, need some suggestions to fix this please.

`Cannot export non-exportable private key when Installing Sitecore10`.

[image]

Note: Already `sitecore9.2` is installed in my system. So `SitecoreRootCert` is already installed.

[image]

Comment: are you using SIA for Sitecore installation?

Comment: Yes @RishirajShekhawat

Comment: delete certificates from c/certificates folder and also from Trusted Root Certificates directory remove DoNotTrsutCertificates  and try installation again.

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat  Tried already, but no luck. after removing these , I am getting this error now.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/sitecore10-installation-error-certenrollcx509privatekeycreate-object-alrea?noredirect=1#comment47023_32186

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue of your `certificate` is not `exportable`.

If you are planning to use your own `SSL certificate` and using `Sitecore installation wizard` then you must make sure that your `SSL certificate` is exportable when you install `SSL` on your server.

[image]

Check the box so your `SSL Certificate` is Exportable for `Sitecore 9.3` Installation

Once you make it exportable then the `Sitecore installation wizard` will be able to export the certificate and continue with the installation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Sumit. but the thing is I forgot the certificate password.

Comment: HI @RashmiRanjan I think this will help you. https://faronics.kayako.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/158/14

Comment: Hi Sumit, I went through this article but it can be possible only that checkbox is selected at the time of installation.

Comment: Now i am getting this, 

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate ------------------]
Could not find Cert: DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert in Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)
[TIME] 00:00:12
CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)

Comment: @RashmiRanjan Please refer this article. The answer given in this article can help you to solve this issue. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25036/sitecore-install-assistant-failing-with-cx509privatekey-access-denied-error/25048#:~:text=During%20the%20installation%20of%20Sitecore%209.3%20on%20a,CertEnroll%3A%3ACX509PrivateKey%3A%3ACreate%3A%20Access%20is%20denied.%200x80070005%20%28WIN32%3A%205%20ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED%29

Comment: The link fixed access denied issue. for me i have full admin access and the issue is object already exits somewhere that i am not able to identify and delete

Comment: @RashmiRanjan I think it would be better to create a new question for this issue. Otherwise the conversation will be to big. And upvote and mark this as complete. So we confirm that this resolved the issue you mentioned in this question. Thanks

Comment: Yes @Sumit, I already have created a new qs . 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/sitecore10-installation-error-certenrollcx509privatekeycreate-object-alrea?noredirect=1#comment47023_32186

Comment: @RashmiRanjan Great. Please mark this question as accepted if this resolved your issue. Thanks