# Sitecore10 installation error: CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f

Tags: sitecore-client, installation

I am getting the below error while installing `Sitecore 10`. Can someone please help me to remove this so that I can reinstall a fresh instance?

Thanks!

log:

```
[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate ------------------]

Could not find Cert: DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert in Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)

[TIME] 00:00:12
CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809 NTE_EXISTS)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the certificate store and removed all the old ones created by SIF?

Comment: @MichaelWest , Yes I have deleted all the  old ones from Personal and Trusted Root Certification folder. So there is no certificate related to Sitecore now.

Comment: @MichaelWest  Is there any other location from where we need to delete as well ?

Comment: Try to also remove from C:\certificates folder.

Comment: @Kamil  no change, getting same error Object already exists

Comment: @RashmiRanjan Are you an Administrator and have full access to windows and install location and mmc console, are you running SIA as admin? Worth to try to install with https://sifon.uk/ tool, this will let you easily choose location of installation, instead of default 'inetpub'.

Comment: @Kamil yes I have admin access and running sia as admin.

Comment: Which object does already exist and where !!! And if it’s there why it’s not overwriting that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by doing the following steps:

1. Created `self-signed root certificate` with the below PowerShell script;

   `New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -FriendlyName "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)`
2. Copied this certificate from Personal to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` inside local machine certificate store