# Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f - while installing Sitecore 10.2

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-assistant

Getting certificate error while installing `Sitecore 10.2` :

```
Error " CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f (-2146893809
NTE_EXISTS)"
```

I have already followed the below link but not getting solution

[image]

[Sitecore10 installation error: CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: Object already exists. 0x8009000f](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/sitecore10-installation-error-certenrollcx509privatekeycreate-object-alrea)

Comment: Can you please try again with reinstallation? Before doing the same, uninstall failed instance completely including the certificate from your dev machine.

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat: There is no failed instance created and already delete certificates  (DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert) from MMC (personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities). Still getting same issue. May be it is organization permission issue , so i want to know which folder or certificate i'll need to get access from organization .

Comment: @RohitThakur Please validate you have access rights to create the certificate in Microsoft Management Console [MMC].

Comment: @SumitBhatia: Yes, I am able to create certificate in MMC. I tried to create "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" using below powershell command and successfully certificate generated:                                                                            New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -FriendlyName "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyProtection None -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)